# How to effectively truncate the head of the file?

Tags: linux, windows, unix, operating-system

Everyone knows the `truncate(file, size)` function, which changes the file size to a given size, by truncating the tail of the file. But how to do the same, only with the truncation of not the tail of the file and his head?

Comment: When the file is a logfile and the program writing to it keeps the filedescriptor open, no more logging will appear after moving the file. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/122942/57293

Comment: open the file, then `sendfile(fd, fd, &offset, size)`, I test on ubuntu 16, works ok, but the older kernel doesn't support

Answer (score 4):

Generally, you have to rewrite the entire file.  The simplest way is to skip the first few bytes, copy everything else to a temporary file, and rename the temporary file on top of the old one when done.  A more elaborate way is to rewrite it in place, analogous to how `memmove` works, with read/seek/write/seek or pread/pwrite, and then truncate the last bit when done.

If you are on a recent version of Linux (>= 3.15), and you have a supported filesystem (currently ext4 or xfs), and the amount you wish to remove happens to be a multiple of the filesystem block size, you could use the non-portable [`fallocate(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fallocate.2.html)  with the `FALLOC_FL_COLLAPSE_RANGE` flag.  Note that this feature is not supported by the portable `posix_fallocate`.

Answer (score 3):

You could just use `tail --lines=<linecount>` to always cap the log file to the last `linecount` lines. This works if you're not trying to truncate to a specific / fixed file size.

Answer (score 2):

The only way is to read the whole file and overwrite it from a needed position.